# Pipe enter to powershell command

Tags: powershell

I try to run exe in a loop in PowerShell, but the program ends with `Press any key to continue`, so my loop hangs.

My code up to now is:

```
foreach ($num in 1..50) { .\somethig.exe }
```

In bash I could use `yes` command but I cannot find anything similar in PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to type in 'y' to get pass the pause,

```
PS> 1..3 | % { write-output y | cmd /c pause }
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
PS> 

PS> 1..50 | % { write-output y | .\something.exe }
```

'%' is an alias for Foreach-Object

Comment: It doesn't work. I got error from application `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console
or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.`

Comment: Is your something.exe a Console or a Windows application?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work with Console.ReadKey(). It does work with Console.ReadLine().   `# 1..3 | % { write-output y | .\ConsoleApplication7.exe }
Oh hai. Press a key.
Key pressed. Exiting.`

Comment: Console.Read() is also fine.

Comment: Your suggestion is incorrect. The behaviour you see is not the result of the write-output sending a y to the pause but the fact that connecting the `cmd /c pause` to a pipe disconnects the command from the console for input. The `pause` then does not wait but ends immediately irrespective of the piped input. You get the same result from `1..3 | % { $null | cmd /c pause }`